# third-party JAR file keep creating threads - How to debug with IntelIJ IDEA?

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, intellij-idea, jar

I'm debugging a third-party JAR file with IntelIJ IDEA Profiler. I could see the number of threads keep increasing, so, How do I know where threads keep being created with IntelIJ IDEA ?

Comment: Try taking a thread dump and look at the stack traces of the individual threads.